# How to capture the text user enters in the `ui:inputText`

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to capture the text user enters in the `ui:inputText`

tried:

```
 var searchText = document.querySelector('.searchKey').value;
```

and tried this as well...

```
 var searchText = component.find("searchKey").get("v.value");
```

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String"/>    
    <div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="searchKey" class="searchKey" keyup="{!c.searchKeyChange}" value="{!v.searchKey}" placeholder="Search..."/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    searchKeyChange: function(component, event) {

        var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:HouseSearchKeyChange");
        var searchText = document.querySelector('.searchKey').value;
        //var searchText = component.find("searchKey").get("v.value");
        myEvent.setParams({"searchKey": document.querySelector(".searchKey").value });
        myEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

> Something has gone wrong. Action failed:
>   c$HouseSearchBar$controller$searchKeyChange [Cannot read property
>   'value' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {c$HouseSearchBar$controller$searchKeyChange}. Please try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your are binding the `ui:inputText` to an aura:attribute `searchKey`. You can directly get the value using `component.get("v.searchKey")`:

```
    var searchText = component.get("v.searchKey");
```

Also, you have to add `updateOn="keyup"` to the `ui:inputText`

**NOTE**: By default aura, updates `searchKey` attribute when the `ui:inputText` loses focus(i.e onblur), since you are access value in `keyup`; we have to explicitly tell aura to *update* the value when there's `keyup` event in the `ui:inputText`.

Comment: i'm still getting `undefined`, when i debug the code from developer console.

Comment: @NickKahn you will get undefined for the first time because on keyup the old value was "undefined", try assigning a default value to the searchKey attribute (or) change the event to be based on button click.

Comment: interesting and i did see that .... second time i see the old value so first time i entered `'jo` i got `undefined` second time i entered `joh` i got `jo`, what event should I use? in order for that to work

Comment: @NickKahn check the updated answer.It would solve the issue.

Comment: @Praveen thanks for the pointer on updateon , I never knew that :)

Comment: @Rao and @NickKahn  By default aura, updates `searchKey` attribute when the `ui:inputText` loses focus(i.e onblur), since you are access value in `keyup`; we have to explicitly tell aura to update the value when there's keyup event in the `ui:inputText`.